# Replace sequence of same characters

Tags: python, regex, text

What is the fastest way in Python to replace sequence of 3 and more same characters in utf-8 text?I need to replace sequence of 3 and more same characters with exact 2 characters.
I.e.

```
aaa -> aa 
bbbb -> bb
abbbcd -> abbcd
124xyyyz3 -> 124xyyz3
```

Comment: Your last example is wrong

Answer (score 12):

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', 'aaa')
'aa'
>>> re.sub(r'(\w)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', 'bbbb')
'bb'
```

Answer (score 7):

You can use regular expression:

```
import re
re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', 'bbbbbaaacc')
```

Pattern captures any character followed by the same character repeated two or more times and matches this substring. The replacement replaces a matched substring with just two of the captured character. Dot will not replace repeated new lines, use `(.|\n)` or `re.DOTALL` flag for that.

It works with Unicode too:

```
re.sub(r'(.)\1{2,}', r'\1\1', u'жжж')
```

And if you have a string variable `x` containing utf-8 text, use `x.decode('utf-8')`.

Comment: It would be great if downvoters would come back one day and un-downvote if the problem has been solved.

Comment: @glglgl I did come back and I upvoted this a long time ago

Answer (score 1):

Although for this specific case I would go for a regular expression, you could also make this generic to operator on arbitrary sequences, eg:

```
from itertools import groupby, chain, islice

s = 'abaaaaaabbbbbbbbcdcddddde'
print ''.join(chain.from_iterable(islice(g, 2) for k, g in groupby(s)))
# abaabbcdcdde
```